# Positioning of divs for Background images

Tags: css, html, background-image, prestashop

Please excuse me if there are any mistakes in the following code or with my question, I don't know much about code but am learning :). Sorry for spaces in links and lack of these things - < - really struggling posting code :)

On my website http:// second to nature .co.uk/en/ I am trying to create background images with ivy down both sides of the website. Is it a prestashop website.

I did manage to achieve this with the following css code, however it would not work in ie 6-8 - because those browsers do not support css3.

```
background:url(http:// second to nature.co.uk/img/backgroundleft.jpg) top left fixed
no-repeat, url(http:// second to nature.co.uk/img/backgroundright.jpg) top right fixed no-repeat;
```

Therefore after some researching, I tried to create the wanted effect with two divs:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then use the following css to implement this.

And as you can see if you visit the site, the left image is shown properly, but the right does not show up.

```
#container {
    background: url(http:// second to nature.co.uk/img/backgroundleft.jpg) repeat-y;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 1000px;
}
    #inner-container {
    background: transparent url(http:// second to nature.co.uk/img/backgroundright.jpg)) repeat-y;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong or have a fix? Help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You have posted `#inner-container` with `background` property, but on your real website I don't see it :) So maybe you should add it first to work?

Comment: It is there. I just had a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your CSS:

```
url(http://secondtonature.co.uk/img/backgroundright.jpg))
```

There is a double )) at the end of the URL where there should be only one.

HOWEVER ... your HTML is all messed up, and there's a better way to do this. Firstly, you have a whole bunch of meta tags and other asset links inside your `body` element, when they should all be up in the `head`.

A better way to do this would be to wrap two divs around your content (they would be 100% width by default) and place the bg images on each of those.

Comment: Thanks so much for that - the simplest thing! :) Which HTML is messed up? The home page?

Comment: It gets quite complicated being Prestashop tho - I have to edit TPL files etc - complicated for me at least.

Comment: It's the same issue on all pages. If you inspect your code on any page (via the web inspector—right click > inspect element in Chrome) you'll see that the `head` section is almost empty. Perhaps try validating your page to see what the problem is.

Comment: Would that be the default in Prestashop tho? I haven't edited any of that myself

Comment: No, there's an error in there somewhere—probably a typo. If nothing else remove those image holder divs into the body of your page. At the moment they are in the head, right after the title element. Perhaps that is confusing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Modernizr and then us CSS3 border image. Then the border image will show up in IE6, 7 and 8.

A shame that you have IE6 users to worry about. It's such a bad, buggy and unsafe browser.

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Looking at the page you're using, there are a  few ways to create the desired effect. You could make an image with ivy running down both sides of the page, and create the content to fall in the middle (probably the best way, and doesn't require CSS3). You could also do the CSS3 method, but create one wrapper container with bordered sides, and place the content in the middle (requires javascript for older browsers).